# Primary key on table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, composite-primary-key

I have table table with featureid,ParameterID,MeasurementDateTime,ParameterValue  will never be duplicated so we have composite key of featureid,ParameterID,MeasurementDateTime. Data is like this

```
 FeatureID  ParameterID MeasurementDateTime ParameterValue
   ASt-1    AP1         1/1/2009 0:00   0.00866667
   ASt-1    AP1         1/1/2009 1:00   0.00608333
   ASt-1    AP1         1/1/2009 2:00   0.016
   ASt-1    AP2         1/1/2009 3:00   0.01091667
   ASt-1    AP2         1/1/2009 4:00   0.01333333
   ASt-1    AP2         1/1/2009 5:00   0.01091667
   ASt-1    AP2         1/1/2009 6:00   0.0195
   ASt-2    AP1         1/1/2009 7:00   0.00733333
   ASt-2    AP1         1/1/2009 8:00   0.02075
   ASt-2    AP1         1/1/2009 9:00   0.00966666
   ASt-2    AP2         1/1/2009 10:00  0.01208333
   ASt-2    AP2         1/1/2009 11:00  0.00966667
   ASt-2    AP2         1/1/2009 12:00  0.01466667
   ASt-2    AP3         1/1/2009 13:00  0.02041666
   ASt-3    AP1         1/1/2009 14:00  0.01233333
   ASt-3    AP1         1/1/2009 15:00  0.0265
   ASt-3    AP1         1/1/2009 16:00  0.011
   ASt-3    AP1         1/1/2009 17:00  0.01383333
   ASt-3    AP2         1/1/2009 18:00  0.0135
   ASt-3    AP3         1/1/2009 19:00  0.009
```

The where clause in most of the queries will be.

```
 1. featureid,ParameterID,year(MeasurementDateTime) 
 2. featureid,ParameterID,year(MeasurementDateTime) and month(MeasurementDateTime)
 3. featureid,ParameterID
```

Please note data is inserted after every one hour and there are nearly 5000 inserts.

Question 1: Is this ok for our data or we should create another non-clustered index on featureid,ParameterID?

Question 2 : Do we need re-index our data periodically?

Comment: 1) Your clustering index is sufficient, although you might want to change it to feature id, parameter id, measurement date time descending.  That way, the more recent measurements will come up first in your queries.  2) If by re-index, you mean drop the indexes and rebuild the indexes, then yes.

Comment: Regarding your query `WHERE` clause, avoid applying `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions to the `MeasurementDateTime` column since the expression is not sargable. Consider and inclusive start date and exclusive end date instead, e.g. `MeasurementDateTime >= @FirstDayOfPeriod AND MeasurementDateTime < @FirstDayOfFollowingPeriod`.

Comment: In order to justify your primary/candidate key, you mean featureid, ParameterID, MeasurementDateTime is never duplicated but featureid, ParameterID, MeasurementDateTime, ParameterValue might be; and you also need that all smaller subrows of featureid, ParameterID, MeasurementDateTime might be duplicated too.